# React app shows nothing in build and after electron-pack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

It works fine in development when i do `npm start` or i do `npm run electron-is-dev` but when i run `npm run build` or `npm run electron-pack` the app doesn't show anything but it shows icon and title on the browser tab.
[screenshot of how app looks after build. shows nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUqbD.png)

How do i fix that.
here is my package.json file.

```
    {
  "name": "cafe-chaska-pos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Touseef Ahmad",
  "description": "Point of sale solution for cafe chaska",
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "homepage": ".",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.13",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.52",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "animated-number-react": "^0.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.2.0",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.17",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "react-toastify": "^6.0.4",
    "uifx": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"yarn start-frontend || npm run start-frontend\" \"yarn start-backend || npm run start-backend\"",
    "start-backend": "nodemon ./server/bin/www",
    "start-frontend": "react-scripts start",
    "install-requirements": "pip install -r server/requirements.txt",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-dev": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
    "electron-pack": "electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js",
    "preelectron-pack": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "electron": "^5.0.8",
    "electron-builder": "^21.1.5",
    "wait-on": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in Developer console?

Comment: you mean browser console?

Comment: or as in development

Comment: Yep, i mean browser console.

Comment: Looking at the screenshoot again, i saw that you open file from local directory. It's not correct way to check the build result. Builded path should need to run from electron ecosystem or run from server like nginx/...

Comment: i get what you are saying but running from electron after eletron-pack produces similar output

Comment: ```npm run electron-is-dev``` runs fine but ```npm run electron-pack``` produces an application and when i launch it it doesn't show anyting.

Comment: As you can see in package.json your script `electron-pack` use the `electron-builder` to build apps for OS. Maybe you need to start from readme of https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder ?